# Why does the error in the Inspect Element show that function myNUM() is not defined ? How to define a function?

Tags: javascript

This code is about Number Validation.I tried this code today and I found difficulties executing it by . The error states that the function is not defined ? Why isn't the function not defined ? How do we come to know that a function is defined ?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<h1>JS can validate number</h1> 

<p><tt>Please enter any number from 1 to 10</tt></p>

<input id="Number">

<button type="button" onclick="myNUM()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myNUM()
{
var x,text;

x=document.getElementById("Number").value;

if
(isNaN(x)||x<1||x>10)

text="Input is not valid";

}

else 
{
text="Input is valid";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u are missing a `{` after `if(isNaN(x)||x<1||x>10)` . Make Sure you don;t have broken javascript. Use Standard Editors where you can validate your HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>My Html Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myNUM()
{
var x,text;

x=document.getElementById("Number").value;

if(isNaN(x)||x<1||x>10)
{
text="Input is not valid";

}

else 
{
text="Input is valid";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>JS can validate number</h1> 

<p><tt>Please enter any number from 1 to 10</tt></p>

<input id="Number">

<button type="button" onclick="myNUM()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try the updated answer. Clear Cache from your browser

Comment: Yes , I realised my mistake.I typed all the codes vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You have not start " { " after " if " statement.

```
    if
    (isNaN(x)||x<1||x>10)
   {
    text="Input is not valid";

   }
```

Comment: Yes ! I gave it a try but the problem is that the function is not being defined